# Open excel file after create it and save it using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, hssfworkbook

I'm using a desktop app java using swing

I'm using JFilechooser to chose the folder to save my excel file

this 1st part is working,the file is well saved. But I need to open it directly after saving it;

I'm using this code the file is found but not open

```
File xlsx = new File(path + ".xls");
        FileInputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(xlsx);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HSSFWorkbook workbook2 = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (xlsx.isFile() && xlsx.exists()) {
            System.out.println("hurray! We've just opened a workbook");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ahh! there was an error. Please make sure that the file path is correct.");
        }
```

I found this `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);` but it works just if I put my file in desktop I need to open it anywhere I save it

thanks for helping

FOUND ANOTHER SOLUTION

UPDATE:

```
File xlsx = new File(path + ".xls");



try {

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL \"" + xlsx + "\"");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } // path from JFileChooser();
```

Comment: What file locations does this not work for?

Comment: for example D: or any other one

Comment: Could not replicate this issue. This will work for any accessible file, regardless of directory (tested to ensure). Ensure that the file exists (so that you are correctly addressing an existing file) before you try and open it. If you get an errors put them in the question.

Comment: there is no error :p but is not open also I found another solution to do it 
see UPDATE thanks